# Magento 2 namespace conflict for custom module

Tags: magento2

I am creating a module with namespace '**Camping**' to customize wishlist.
I have copied '**wishlist_index_index.xml**' to my module and changed as per need.
but its not yet working.
When I change the namespace to any other name, my custom wishlist start working.

my module structure is Camping/Wishlist/

Can any one tell why its not working with namespace '**Camping**' ????

this is my wishlist_index_index.xml file located in Camping/Wishlist/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="wishlist_head_components" template="Magento_Wishlist::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="view.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="item/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Camping\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">configured_price</argument>
                            <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.inner" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-inner</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="item/column/cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.actions" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-actions</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Edit" name="customer.wishlist.item.edit" template="item/column/edit.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="item/column/remove.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <container name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons" label="Wishlist Control Buttons">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="button/update.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="button/share.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="button/tocart.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            </container>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

I have created my own block named Image.php and image.phtml also with custom code.

Comment: Module works after changed namespace or both namespace and module name ?

Comment: if I use Camping as namespace, its not working i have not changed my module name

Comment: plz show your full xml file

Comment: I have just copy and paste the xml file and was trying to change as per the requirement. but its not working. The issue is I have to use this namespace only 'Camping'. I have defined in composer.json , registration.php and module.xml also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you have to just override block file.
You have to do it using override wishlist block with your custom block.
So you doesn't need to do override `wishlist_index_index.xml` file.

Remove `wishlist_index_index.xml` file from layout.

Just do below to works:

add `di.xml` file inside **`etc`** folder.

`etc/di.xml` file code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" type="Camping\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" />
</config>
```

Block file path (add Image.php inside below folder),

```
Camping\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column
```

now code for block file,

```
<?php    
namespace Camping\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column;

class Image extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image
{
    protected $_template = 'item/column/image.phtml';

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        //echo 'tests';exit;
        if ($this->isEnabled()) {
            if (!$this->getLayout()) {
                return '';
            }
            foreach ($this->getLayout()->getChildBlocks($this->getNameInLayout()) as $child) {
                if ($child) {
                    $child->setItem($this->getItem());
                }
            }
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

You can override `image.phtml` file inside `app/code/Camping/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/column/image.phtml`

view file,

```
<?php
/* @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
$item = $block->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
?>
This is override file called.
<a class="product-item-photo" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getImage($product, 'wishlist_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
</a>
```

please let me know if any issue occurs,

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried this also but its not working.

Comment: <block class="Camping\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="camping.wishlist.item.image" template="Camping_Wishist::item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>

Comment: Any help please.......

Comment: i need to change design and functionality of wishlist page. like changing the css and other with extra functionality. i have overrided wishlist,item,image,price and other blocks, just by placing my block and template in layout xml filie. I have done all changes but with other namespace as 'Test'. but my client need only ''Camping" as namespace as many other modules are built inside that namespace. which i am not able to complete.

Comment: plz check for updated answer.